# DocuSign returning HTML from Authentication only when the application is under a domain

Tags: docusignapi

i'm integrating the docusign api with my angular application, everything is working good, i created a proxy configuration in order to do the api calls, im using the demo url since i have a demo developer account.
The problem is that when i run my program in local (using localhost) the authentication token is successfully returned by the oauth call but when i upload my program on an external domain the same call returns me an html with irrelevant information with status 200 OK.
I tried to search this on google but i can't find nothing good.
What should i do?

this is the error i get:
ERROR qm
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
at XMLHtt…, text: "<!doctype html>↵↵↵  <meta ch…b0a19788ec.js" defer="">↵↵"}headers: DmlazyInit: ()=> {…}lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(0) {}**proto**: Objectmessage: "Http failure during parsing for http://frontendly.it/oauth/token"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 200statusText: "OK"url: "http://frontendly.it/oauth/token"**proto**: Bm

Comment: What's the exact URL are you hitting when you get the HTML response?

Comment: http://frontendly.it/oauth/token, "frontendly.it" is the domain, im using a proxy

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth call you are making has a parameter called redirectUri.
Look for `&redirect_uri=` in the URL.
You have to change that for each location, if you put this in a domain - then you cannot use localhost in there.

This URL has to match exactly to where you deployed your application.

For the second call, make sure to make it a POST, not GET, add the headers like this: ([more information](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/))

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic NWMyYjhkN.....FhODg2MQ=="
--data "grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJ0eXAi.....QFsje43QVZ_gw"
--request POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
```

Comment: The redirect link is the same as the domain, i changed its not localhost, i can get the code for authentication but not the token using this call "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token", i tried also the same call using the prod url but its returning always the same thing

Comment: how are you making this call? I assume from the server? what lang? You do need to POST call, not GET, you need to put some headers. Let me update my answer with example using cURL

Comment: My call is complete and it is in POST, in fact it is working while I'm in localhost with a proxy configuration in order to skip cors policies, but i think that when i upload my application in my server my proxy configuration fails and then I receive the html, I don't know how can I skip these cors policies while my app is online

Comment: to use CORS read the following - https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-building-single-page-applications-with-docusign-and-cors-part-2

Comment: is there any method to skip that? maybe by disabling cors

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to make the authentication calls from the client.